# Apply background color to the width of the text and center it

Tags: html, css

When I apply background color to a text and try to center it, the background color takes up the whole webpage's width. I wanted the bg color to take up the text's size only.

> > HTML

```
<div class="order">
    <h3>Hello world</h3>
    <h1>How are you doing</h1>
</div>
```

> > CSS

```
.order h3,
.order h1, {
text-align: center;
}

.order h3 {
display: inline-flex;
font-family: Raleway;
color: white;
background-color: var(--main-color);
}

.order h1 {
  font-family: Raleway;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code (using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)):

```css
.order {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.order h3 {
  font-family: Raleway;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.order h1 {
  font-family: Raleway;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="order">
    <h3>Hello world</h3>
    <h1>How are you doing</h1>
</div>
```

---

You can adjust the `background-color` and add it where needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the `<span>` tag is designed for.

```css
.order {
    text-align: center;
}

.order h3 > span {
    font-family: Raleway;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}

.order h1 > span {
  font-family: Raleway;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="order">
    <h3><span>Hello world</span></h3>
    <h1><span>How are you doing</span></h1>
</div>
```

As described by [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp);

The `<span>` tag is an inline container used to mark up a part of a text, or a part of a document.

The `<span>` tag is easily styled by CSS or manipulated with JavaScript using the class or id attribute.

The `<span>` tag is much like the `<div>` element, but `<div>` is a block-level element and `<span>` is an inline element.